# APEX accessing subquery

Tags: apex

```
list<Opportunity> opportunity=[select Type, TotalOpportunityQuantity, TM_Quote_ID__c, StageName, SKI_Number__c, Probability, Name,KIS_Number__c, HasOpportunityLineItem, ForecastCategoryName, ForecastCategory, Amount,AccountId, Opportunity_Number__c, (Select Id, PricebookEntryId, Product2Id, ProductCode, Name, Quantity, Discount,TotalPrice, UnitPrice, ListPrice, ServiceDate, Description, Recurring_Charge__c, TM_Forecast_Type__c, 
Product_Account__c, Product_Account_Description__c From OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where opportunity_number__c=:lOpportunity[0].opportunity_number__c];

system.assertequals(opportunity[0].opportunitylineitems__r.quantity,tmquote.productList[0].quantity);
```

this assertequals says that invalid foreign key relationship so how do i access fields from opportunitylineitem from the subquery of the list??

Answer (score 0):

It returns a list, change it to:

```
system.assertequals(opportunity[0].opportunitylineitems[0].quantity,tmquote.productList[0].quantity);
```

When you access child records it return List of Child Sobjects.And standard sobject/fields doesn't require `__r`